# Используют ли Github Desktop в IT-компаниях?

Tags: git

Вопрос такой: на проектах для управления версий использовать интерфейс Github Desktop — это норм или все искоса в компании могут посмотреть типа мы есть командная строка и зовут нас командная строка?

А если чуток серьезно, у командной строки есть преимущества против интерфейса

Comment: Очень по разному. Кто-то пользуется, а кто-то нет. Есть люди, которые гитом пользуются прямо в IDE. Используйте то что Вам удобно.

Comment: А какие преимущества у командной строки, кроме как что она не кушает ресурсы ПК?

Comment: @Tsyklop спасибо через 2 дня на первую работу хочу заранее знать некоторые нюансы которые не загуглиш

Comment: @АлексейШиманский знать не знаю может какие то команды которых в интерфейсе нет?

Comment: @Armen для нестандартных ситуаций - возможно. Для регулярной работы UI более чем. (Я например в PHPStrom использую и там их десятки и ещё не было случаев, чтобы чего-то не было)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо)

Comment: Довольно странно, что мы противопоставляем Github Desktop (довольно ограниченный GUI-клиент) и командную строку. Что насчет других графических оболочек, хотя бы тот же Git GUI из стандартной поставки? Командная строка имеет приемущества, но не просматривать же историю коммитов через нее, это будет просто безумием.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight или разбираться с конфликтами в файле в тысячу строк)))

Comment: Я только через терминал и пользуюсь. Очень редко гуи нужно